# How to customize the Theme for whole Application

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I used `Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar` for my whole Application. Now the Action bar background color is black by default. How to change this color. Basically how to customize the      Theme for whole Application?

```
<activity
            android:name="com.mypath.myapp.FirstActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar"
            >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `android:theme=theme_style` in your `<application>` tag. Now if you want your action bar to be different than that given by the theme, then you can override it by defining the style between `<style></style` for your action bar specifically.

Here's the concept. Go to `res > values > styles.xml`. You can **extend** or customize your themes as follows:

```
     <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
          <item name="android:background">@color/background_dark</item>
      </style>
```

**Update:**
OR if you want to make generic (not theme specific) changes for all your applications, then you can edit `sdk/platforms/android-target/data/res/values/styles.xml`

OR if you want to override default themes for all your applications, then you can edit `sdk/platforms/android-target/data/res/values/themes.xml`

**Update - found this:**

[ActionBar developer docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html). This link says "You can control the behaviors and visibility of the action bar with the ActionBar APIs, which were added in Android 3.0 (API level 11)." So I assume your target is API 11 at minimum.

If you are targeting API 11 and above, you can do advanced custom styling as follows:

```
    <resources>
            <style name="CustomActivityTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
                <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
            </style>

            <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
                <item name="android:background">@drawable/ab_background</item>
                <item name="android:backgroundStacked">@drawable/ab_background</item>
              <item name="android:backgroundSplit">@drawable/ab_split_background</item>
            </style>
    </resources>
```

Here you go , [Styling Action Bar background](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#AdvancedStyles)

Comment: Here what is android:theme=theme_style? is it android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme"

Comment: Yes. It's a style resource of the theme.

Comment: @Ram , I've updated my answer. Apparently , what you are trying can be done from API 11 and onwards. The XML above is straight from Android Developer docs. Have posted the links.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the theme for your whole application in your manifest file in application tag as below:

> ```
>  <application
>     android:name="com.test"
>     android:icon="@drawable/appicon"
>     android:label="@string/app_name"
>     android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" > <---Define your own style here.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://actionbarsherlock.com/theming.html . You must create a own Theme-style.

Answer (score 0):

for modifying default android sdk themes You can find android Sdk themes.xml file in :

```
\android-sdk\platforms\...\data\res\values\themes.Xml
```

so you can change your whole application theme.